# Recommendations for an FTP server that would allow limiting folder size for users

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, ftp

I'm currently using FileZilla FTP server, which is a nice free server but running into issues of not being able to limit/set quotas for folder which users have access to.

Anybody know of an FTP server that would allow limiting how much a user could upload to their root folder?

Forgot to mention this is for Win 2008/03.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 2003R2 and newer have support for NTFS directory-quotas. While not built into the IIS FTP server, the IIS FTP server will honor them. We've found dir-quotas a more flexible solution than user-quotas overall. They're managed through the File Server Resource Manager.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com) on Windows 2003 and 2008 and it does all that you require and more.  Cost effective and very feature rich.  Great support as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really the ftp server's task to ensure disk utilization for users. I am not sure what kind of your users you have but you could use the standard quota facility.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733029.aspx